# create a new column which holds values of another column plus NA values from a third column

Tags: r, time-series, portfolio, quantitative-finance

I have a time series data of the format

```
            Time   Size Ask    Bid    Trade
11-1-2016   9:00:12 100 <NA>    901     <NA>
11-1-2016   9:00:21 5   <NA>    <NA>    950
11-1-2016   9:00:21 5   <NA>    950     <NA>
11-1-2016   9:00:21 10  905     <NA>    <NA>
11-1-2016   9:00:24 500 <NA>    921     <NA>
11-1-2016   9:00:28 2   <NA>    879     <NA>
11-1-2016   9:00:31 6   1040    <NA>    <NA>
11-1-2016   9:00:39 5   <NA>    <NA>    950
11-1-2016   9:00:39 5   <NA>    950     <NA>
11-1-2016   9:00:39 10  905     <NA>    <NA>
```

And the structure of the data is

```
'data.frame':   35797 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Time : POSIXct, format: "2016-11-01 09:00:12" "2016-11-01 09:00:21" ..
 $ Size : chr  "100" "5" "5" "10" ...
 $ ASk  : chr  NA NA NA "905" ...
 $ Bid  : chr  "901" NA "950" NA ...
 $ Trade: chr  NA "950" NA NA ...
```

Now I would like to have another column named "Ask_Size" which will take the data from the Column "Size" for each data in Column "Ask". If the data in Column in Ask is "NA" then the corresponding value in column "Ask_Size" will also be "NA"

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways of doing this. First find non-NA values and multiply the Size colum with this vector. Where NA will be present, the result will be 0. Change that zero to NA.

```
xy <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = c(NA, 3, 1))

xy$c <- xy$a * !is.na(xy$b)
xy[xy$c == 0, "c"] <- NA
xy

  a  b  c
1 1 NA NA
2 2  3  2
3 3  1  3
```

Or, you could copy Size and change all values where Ask is NA to NA.

```
xy$c <- xy$a
xy[is.na(xy$b), "c"] <- NA
```